# Scala Mapping from a class to a matching generic

Tags: scala, generics

I'd like to create a map in scala from a ClassTag to MyHelperClass[that class], something like this (which doesn't compile because maps don't support this sort of element-wise pattern matching):

```
import scala.reflect._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

val MAP_CONSTANT = map[ClassTag[T], MyHelperClass[T]](
  classTag[SomeClass] -> helperForSomeClass,
  classTag[AnotherClass] -> helperForAnotherClass,
)
```

Is there a good way to do this? I need the compiler to know that the helper returned is generic to the same class as the input class tag.

I'd rather not do a match with several cases because

- It would be uglier code
- It would be hard to build confidence in such code without an equally ugly test
- match iteratively checks each condition, which could be slow with many possible helpers

Answer (score 0):

This is called a typeclass and is more more elegantly solved with context bounds and implicit parameters.

```
trait MyHelperClass[T] {
  def takeOverTheWorld: Unit = ..
}
object MyHelperClass {
  def apply[T : MyHelperClass]: MyHelperClass[T] = implicitly[MyHelperClass[T]]
}
```

Now all you need to do is to define a bunch of helpers:

```
class X
class Y

object Helpers {
  implicit object XHelper extends MyClassHelper[X] {
    override def takeOverTheWorld: Unit = println("Hey I'm X")
  }

  implicit object YHelper extends MyClassHelper[Y] {
    override def takeOverTheWorld: Unit = println("Hey I'm actually an Y")
  }


  def doAction[T : MyHelperClass]: Unit = MyHelperClass[T].takeOverTheWorld
  doAction[X] // will print "Hey I'm an X"
  doAction[Y] // will print "Hey I'm actually an Y"
}
```

The `def x[T : MyHelperClass]` is shorthand syntax for `def x[T]()(implicit ev: MyHelperClass[T])`

Comment: This looks really promising, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. Specifically, I have a function generic to T of any type:
`process[T](data: Seq[T])(implicit helper: MyHelperClass[T]): ...`
I would like to throw on runtime if T does not match a helper, but I cannot compile:
`could not find implicit value for parameter helper: com...MyHelperClass[_$1]`

Comment: @mwlon Why would you ever prefer runtime over compile time? That makes little sense from a code quality perspective, I'd rather know "I'm wrong" sooner rather than later. If a user wants to implement a `MyHelperClass` for a give type `T`, then they can simply do `implicit object bla extends MyHelperClass[T]` themselves, so you are not preventing people from adding helpers down the line, if that's your concern. Any other reason to prefer runtime?

Comment: Let's say I have a seq of X's and Y's and want to apply the corresponding implicit helper to each one. If I try to do
`val entries = Seq[_](new X(), new Y()); entries.foreach(entry => Helpers.doAction(entry))` I get the same error. How can I enforce a constraint on the _ that all entries can be implicitly converted to MyHelperClass?

Comment: I'm not sure you can via `Seq`, you may need an HList with an LUB constraint, let me double check that.